# postgres log queries for other database/application but not mine

Tags: postgresql

i need to see the performance of the queries in a Java app which use JPA/Hibernate/postgres, took me a while to find the postgres log file

```
/var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data/pg_log/postgresql-*.log
```

however i only found the queries from other application on other database,

i tried to modify the postgresql.conf to add

```
log_statement = 'all'
```

how can i make postgres to log my queries too? and how i can do it in my code?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the postgresql.conf setting will log all queries on all databases.  You must restart (or at least reload) PostgreSQL after editing that setting (out of habit I always do a restart).

Other options are available though which are not such of a broad stroke (and these override that setting so may be also causing your issue:

```
ALTER USER foo SET log_statements = 'all';
```

This will log all statements by database user foo.

```
ALTER DATABASE foo SET log_statements = 'all';
```

This will log all statements in the foo database.  Iirc the order of precidence is user, database, postgresql.conf value.